# Swift Generic Callback

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am currently learning on how to implement a generic function. I am trying to create a function that will return a callback with generic type

Here is my code

```
static func performPOST<T: DomainEntity>(action: Module, completion: @escaping (CallbackResponse, DomainObjectWrapper<T>?) -> Void) {

     //logic implementation at first

     switch action { 
          case .getMenuItem:
          self.alamofireManager.request(urlRequest, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<DomainObjectWrapper<MenuItemDO>>) in
                var validateRequestResponse = RestHelper.validateRequestResponse(response: response)
                let responseObject = validateRequestResponse.responseObject

                if validateRequestResponse.isSuccess {}
                else {
                    if let errorMessage = responseObject?.error {
                        validateRequestResponse.message = errorMessage
                    }
                    else if let warningMessage = responseObject?.warning {
                        validateRequestResponse.message = warningMessage
                    }
                }
                callbackResponse = RestHelper.bindValidateRequestResponse(validateRequestResponse: validateRequestResponse)
                completion(callbackResponse, responseObject)
            }
          case .makeSales: break
          case .attendance: break
     }
}
```

I am getting this error from the Xcode. It won't let me compile.

```
completion(callbackResponse, responseObject) <<-- This Line

Cannot convert value of type 'DomainObjectWrapper<MenuItemDO>?' to expected argument type 'DomainObjectWrapper<_>?'
```

Here is my other classes

```
public class DomainObjectWrapper<T: Mappable>: Mappable {
     public var data = [T]()
}

public class DomainEntity: Mappable {
     public var id = UUID().uuidString
     public var isDeleted = false
}

public class MenuItemDO: DomainEntity {
     public var categoryId: String?
     public var categoryName: String?
}
```

Can anybody guide me on what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: How do you call that method? On which line do you receive the error? Can you update the question with these details?

Comment: Why do you think your method should be generic?

Comment: Hi @Cristik, the Xcode won't compile the code. The error from the compiler is stated above. Thanks

Comment: @Sweeper, because there will be lots of API call that will return DomainObjectWrapper<DifferentValue>. So i guess creating a generic function will help me to avoid redundant code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because there will be lots of API call that will return DomainObjectWrapper. So i guess creating a generic function will help me to avoid redundant code. Thanks

If that's the case, then you would use `DataResponse<DomainObjectWrapper<T>>` instead of `DataResponse<DomainObjectWrapper<MenuItemDO>>` in the closure parameter of the Alamofire call:

```
static func performPOST<T: DomainEntity>(action: Module, completion: @escaping (CallbackResponse, DomainObjectWrapper<T>?) -> Void) {

     //logic implementation at first

     switch action { 
          // this line
          self.alamofireManager.request(urlRequest, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<DomainObjectWrapper<T>>) in // <----- this line
                var validateRequestResponse = RestHelper.validateRequestResponse(response: response)
                let responseObject = validateRequestResponse.responseObject

                if validateRequestResponse.isSuccess {}
                else {
                    if let errorMessage = responseObject?.error {
                        validateRequestResponse.message = errorMessage
                    }
                    else if let warningMessage = responseObject?.warning {
                        validateRequestResponse.message = warningMessage
                    }
                }
                callbackResponse = RestHelper.bindValidateRequestResponse(validateRequestResponse: validateRequestResponse)
                completion(callbackResponse, responseObject)
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sweeper. Thank you so much for your response. I am getting error on the completion() code. Basically my responseObject is correct. However, somehow the parent callback function wont recognize my completion block inside the switch case (the responseObject). Hopefully you get what I mean. Thanks

Comment: @Alvin Oh I just realised! Why doesn't your `switch` have `case`s? And what error are you getting?

Comment: Hi, actually there is, I am just trying to keep my code simple for the explanation here :). The error is the one that I have stated on my question :). Thanks!

Comment: @Alvin Did you change `DataResponse<DomainObjectWrapper<MenuItemDO>>` to `DataResponse<DomainObjectWrapper<T>>` like I told you to do? If so the error message should not appear. Or do you mean you are getting an error calling `performPOST`?

Comment: I changed it. But I couldn't get my MenuItemDO property. I couldn't get the data from the JSON. I can only get DomainEntity property. Any workaround on it? Or my function is wrong at beginning? I have updated my other classes structure. Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: @Alvin That is to be expected, isn't it? You are not supposed to be able to access `MenuItemDTO` properties in your `performPost` method because `T` could be any type that inherits `DomainEntity`. `T` doesn't have to be `MenuItemDTO`. You can either not make the method generic, or access the properties you want from the caller side.

Comment: So, basically I cannot make a generic function of this scenario? I am trying to avoid redundant code. Because if let's say there are 100 of API calls. I must copy paste the codes 100 times and then change my callback dataresponse class? Please guide me on what best approach to use :)

Comment: @Alvin If you have a 100 `DataResponse` classes, why do you think you can access properties of `MenuItemDTO`? That's too specific. Generic methods should be very general. You can access them when you call the method though. Maybe do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189862/discussion-between-alvin-and-sweeper).

Answer (score 0):

Recently I made an ok solution for generic parameter functions. Here's an example for the command pattern. This way you could use this pattern receiving a callback with generic parameter.

```
protocol ParameterCommand {
    func execute(with parameter: Any)
}

protocol CallbackCommand: ParameterCommand {
    associatedtype CallBackParameterType
    func execute(with callback: @escaping (CallBackParameterType) -> Void)
}

extension CallbackCommand {
    func execute(with parameter: Any) {
        if let parameter = parameter as? (CallBackParameterType) -> Void {
            execute(with: parameter)
        }
    }
}
```